# What is the @ sign on the end of file permission on terminal?

Tags: terminal, iphone, file-permissions

I have a sound file in my app that the iPhone does not play.
After checking other problems I checked the file permission in terminal.

What I can see is that the file permission of this file has a- @ at the end of it. I don't know if that is the problem but this is the only difference from the other sound files that plays fine.

1. What is this sign ?
2. Could it cause a problem ?

**EDIT**

Thanks

this is what I get:

```
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  4D 34 41 20 68 6F 6F 6B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |M4A hook........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
```

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "@" sign (which is not documented in the manual page for ls) indicates that the file has extended attributes. You can use the command `xattr -l <filename>` to show them.

As for how to read it, this is a representation of the structure of the hexadecimal data:

```
struct finder_info {
    char[4] filetype; // x,y coords of top left corner for directories
    char[4] creator; // x,y coords for bottom right corner for directories
    char[2] finder_flags;
    char[2] finder_loc_v;
    char[2] finder_loc_h;
    char[2] opaque1; // Icon ID?

    char[2] scroll_position_v;
    char[2] scroll_position_h;
    char[2] reserved1;
    char[6] opaque_finder_flags
    char[2] reserved2;
    char[2] putAwayFolderID;
};
```

To solve your problem, I have found [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-841825.html) workaround:

> On your Desktop, use Finder to make an empty new folder, and name it
>   Foo.
>
> While holding the option key, drag the video files into the Foo
>   folder. This copies rather than just moves the files.
>
> Then, in Terminal, enter the following lines, one at a time:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Desktop
> cp -XR Foo NewFoo
> cd NewFoo
> ls -@l
> ```
>
> Are the @ signs gone? Can you open the files now?

Comment: Thanks @m4573r Edited my question, how do I read it ?

Comment: Hey. I simply deleted this data with xattr -c <filename> and it works great now. Thanks For you help.